# how to send data to remote device over udp?

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to establish connection between calamp lmu (gps tracking device) and my server. 
i am using following code to send and receive data.
i am using timer1 to receive data from device

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Try
        Dim receiveBytes As [Byte]() = receivingUdpClient.Receive(remoteEP)
        Dim returnData As String = BitConverter.ToString(receiveBytes)
        txtLog.Text &= returnData.ToString & vbCrLf

        Dim rep As New IPEndPoint(remoteEP.Address, C_DEVICE_LISTNING_PORT)

        sktSocket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)
        sktSocket.Connect(remoteEP.Address, 20510)
        sktSocket.SendTimeout = 100

        'Dim udc As New UdpClient
        'udc.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, rep)

        'receivingUdpClient.Client.Send(sendBytes)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

following two variables are class level:

```
Dim remoteEP As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0)
Dim sktSocket As Socket
```

i am using following code to send data to device:

```
 Private Sub butSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butSend.Click
        Dim sendBytes() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtCommand.Text)
        sktSocket.Send(sendBytes)
    End Sub
```

my code to receive data works fine. when device sends data timer1 displays it in a textbox. But when i send data to the ip address returned by receivingUdpClient.Receive, it does not reach to the device. however wireshark shows that data has been sent.

any help will be appriciated.

Comment: why is there a connect in your code ? Udp is not connection oriented, so connect is not usually done.

Comment: i have also tried to send without connect as in following but same result:
 Dim udc As New UdpClient(remoteEP.Address.ToString, 20510)
 udc.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length)
 udc.Close()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved my problem myself. actually nothing was wrong in the code. actually i was connecting the device using forwarded port. it was hindering inward traffic from device to my system. Assigning static ip direct to my system solved the problem.